# Number from plist displayed with two decimal places using NSNumberFormatter

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsstring, nsnumber, nsnumberformatter

I'm displaying a Number from a plist in one of my labels (if key exists). If i typed in 98,90 in the plist it sometimes changed the number to i.e 98,9000000000001. So I want to display the numbers with two decimal places, and I'm trying to add a `NSNumberFormatter` to do the job. But I can't make it work, I need some help to do it right. This is my try:

```
 NSString *theString = @"";
 if ([selectedObject valueForKey:@"75 cl"] != nil) {

     NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
     [formatter setPositiveFormat:@"###.##"];

     theString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"75 cl € %@", [formatter stringFromNumber:[selectedObject valueForKey:@"75 cl"]]];
 }
 sevenfiveLabel.text = theString;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to use a `NSNumberFormatter`:

```
NSString *theString = @"";
NSNumber *theNumber = [selectedObject valueForKey:@"75 cl"];

if (theNumber) {
    theString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"75 cl € %.2f", [theNumber floatValue]];
}

sevenfiveLabel.text = theString;
```

Comment: d'oh! Yup! Sorry... my bad :)

Answer (score 1):

A `#` in the format string represents an optional digit: the formatter will only put a digit there if it needs to.  If you want to force it to pad out the string, you need to use a `0` in the format string.

```
Format   Result
###.##   98.9
##0.00   98.90
000.00   098.90
```